# OutOfMemory Exception thrown at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String value)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method which is called in loop to generate .c and .h file and its content is determined by string template. But after generating around >4000 files, I am facing OutOfMemory exception.

After following through stack trace, I found that the exception is thrown at WriteLine method of `StreamWriter (System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String value))`
Generated files are:
-   .c files - Around 4.5 – 6.5 MB and .h files – around 5KB
-   There are more than 4000 files getting generated.
-   I am also using StreamWriter inside using statement for auto flush

```
    protected virtual void WriteFile ( string fileName, string content )
    {
        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName ( fileName );
        if ( Directory.Exists( directoryName ) == false )
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory ( directoryName );
        }

        // ensure consistent line ending

        using ( var sw = new StreamWriter ( fileName ) )
        {
            sw.WriteLine(EnsureWindowsStyleLineEnding(content));
        }
    }


    private string EnsureWindowsStyleLineEnding(string content)
    {
        // convert all linux or mixed line endings (\n) to windows line endings (\r\n)
        // first ensure that all are linux
        string linux = new StringBuilder(content).Replace("\r\n", "\n").ToString();
        // now convert all to windows
        string windows = new StringBuilder(linux).Replace ("\n", "\r\n").ToString();
        return windows;
    }
```

Please suggest how can I resolve this out of memory exception.

Comment: Hrm there is seemingly more to this story, there is no indication any of the above would throw an `OutOfMemoryException` on multiple runs.

Comment: Whats the biggest file you are dealing with ?

Comment: All generated files are of size between 5 - 7 MB

Comment: Have you tried using a memory profiler? I expect the issue not in the code we're seeing. We're seeing just the code which get's no more memory from OS.

Comment: @jalsh it didnt resolved the issue. Same behavior as earlier.

Comment: Is your program which calls this method just a sequential loop, or is there any parallellism involved?

Comment: @JonasHøgh it is a sequential loop

Comment: @ManojJha did find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Please see if below helps or not.

```
private StringBuilder changeLineEnding = new StringBuilder();

private string EnsureWindowsStyleLineEnding(string content)
{
    changeLineEnding.Clear();
    // convert all linux or mixed line endings (\n) to windows line endings (\r\n)
    // first ensure that all are linux
    changeLineEnding.Append(content);
    changeLineEnding = changeLineEnding.Replace("\r\n", "\n");

    // now convert all to windows
    changeLineEnding = changeLineEnding.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
    return changeLineEnding.ToString();
}
```

You are doing a lot of string operations, and the memory allocated would be released by GC on it's own and that could take time.

Comment: Still OOM exception is there.

Comment: Hi @ManojJha Is it possible to provide a working example where the program is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggested solution, just write it line by line:

```
protected virtual void WriteFile ( string fileName, string content )
{
    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName ( fileName );
    if ( Directory.Exists( directoryName ) == false )
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory ( directoryName );
    }

    // ensure consistent line ending

    using ( var sw = new StreamWriter ( fileName ) )
    {
        foreach (line in content.Split('\n')) sw.WriteLine(line.Trim('\r'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try to clear the buffer manually:

```
 using ( var sw = new StreamWriter ( fileName ) )
 {
    sw.WriteLine(EnsureWindowsStyleLineEnding(content));
    sw.Flush(); // clear buffer manually 
 }
```

Comment: that's totally redundant

Comment: it's just like if I suggested a solution that he should explicitly declare the type `StreamWrite sw = new StreamWriter(filename);` it's redundant, hence, it's not an answer...

Comment: I believe that the StreamWriter was not closed when he trying to write a lot of files in a loop, that is why I propose just to clear the buffer manually.

Comment: this file can be opened in several threads from different places and the 'using' will never close the stream

Comment: using **will** dispose of the stream, closing it eventually, look at [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement). It's even safer than your _manual_ call by that if an exception occurs, it'll still dispose of the instance... if another thread is using the stream and the current thread reached the end of the `using` statement, an exception will occur in the other thread that it'd be using a disposed resource.. try it